# How to parse data from firebase to MUI DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, datagrid, material-ui

I'm trying to learn how to parse data from firebase to MaterialTable because it looks way more clean than doing it "manually" with maps and `<th>` , `<tr>` but I haven't seen any tutorial that links MaterialTable + firebase. All tutorials so far show you can parse some manual data like this:

[image]

But not a single one with firebase included. any documentations/tips/help is welcome.

My code so far:

Data from firebase (working)

```
const [estudiantes, setEstudiantes] = useState([]);
const estudiantesRef = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid).collection("estudiantes")

  useEffect(() => {
    estudiantesRef
    .orderBy('name')
     .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
       
        const tempData = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

          const data = doc.data();
          tempData.push(data);

        });
        setEstudiantes(tempData);
      })
  }, []);
```

Columns (Working)

```
const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 100 },

  {field: 'nombre', headerName: 'Nombre', width: 200},

  {field: 'colegio', headerName: 'Colegio', width: 250},

  {field: 'grado', headerName: 'Grado', width: 150}
]
```

And how i'm "rendering" the table (Working)

```
return (
        <div className = "table_container" >
      <DataGrid
        rows={tempData}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
    )
}

export default ListadoEstudiantes
```

My data half attempt (I'm constantly trying stuff)

```
const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {

  estudiantes.map((estudiantes, index) => ({
    setData(estudiantes[index])
  }))
}, [estudiantes])
```

that's giving me an error so far but I'll keep trying stuff until I get it. This is how I expect to make it look with the data from Firebase

[image]

Any tips/documentation/help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Apparently you don't have to do anything fancy I found out that as long as the variables names inside your doc(). match the ones you set up in your columns options

Set up in the code:

[image]

in the code you can see when I set up the values it matches with the names of the columns variables

```
const register = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const docRef = db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes').doc();
      docRef.set({
        nombre: firstName + " " + lastName,
        colegio: escuela,
        grado: grado,
        uid: docRef.id,

      }).then((r) => {
          history.push("/Inicio");
      })
    }
```

How it should look in the firebase (still matching the columns)

[image]

Finally the result:

[image]